# Email template - Inline sections are not aligning completely left and right in outlook

Tags: html, css

I am using Email template , in which my second tr section[image] should be aligned to totally left and right. Right part is not coming completely right. I have used table inside td here. For emails in browser is working fine but in outlook 365 is not aligning properly. I have tested using litmus putsmail email tester. Here is the code below

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <table style="width:60%;font-size:18px;background-color:#F5F5F5;padding:10px" align="center" border="0"
        cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;float:left">
                            <b>Lorem ipsum is a dummy text used to replace text in some areas</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right;float:right">
                            <b>Lorem ipsum is a dummy text used to replace text in some areas</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="float:left"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></td>
                        <td style="float:right"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="float:left">Lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td style="float:right">Lorem ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="float:left">Lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td style="float:right">Lorem ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those texts to align or position at extremes, we can use

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
```

For that, first assign a class `class = "table-items"` to the `<tr>`s in second `<tr>` section.

```
       <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr class = "table-items">
                        <td><b>Lorem ipsum</b></td>
                        <td><b>Lorem ipsum</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class = "table-items">
                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class = "table-items">
                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Now, what happens is, elements in `<tr class = "table-items"` will have a display flex, direction row, and the content inside `<td>` tags which is inside `<tr class="table-items">` will be at extremes in a row.

add `style` tag in `head` and then add the below code in it.

```
<style>
    .table-items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Its not working , same issue when I test with litmus